# Lexical error running sql in netbeans 8.02

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I new to java DB programming.I am trying out create  tables in GlassFish Server 4.1 using sql statements but whenever I run the sql using the run sql tool, it gives me the following errors
Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 3, column 3.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 1, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 3, column 3.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 13, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 3, column 3.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 31, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 49, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 14.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 59, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 14.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 63, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 14.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 67, column 1
here is my sql source code
    CREATE TABLE groups (

```
  `group_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `group_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

  `group_desc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`)

);

CREATE TABLE users (

  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `username` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

  `first_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,

  `middle_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,

  `last_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,

  `password` char(32) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)

);

CREATE TABLE user_groups (

  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `group_id` int(10) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`group_id`),

  KEY `fk_users_has_groups_groups1` (`group_id`),

  KEY `fk_users_has_groups_users` (`user_id`),

  CONSTRAINT `fk_groups` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups`    
  (`group_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`   
  (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

 ); 

CREATE VIEW `v_user_role` AS

SELECT  u.username, u.password, g.group_name

 FROM `user_groups` ug

 INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.user_id = ug.user_id

 INNER JOIN `groups` g ON g.group_id =  ug.group_id; 

 INSERT  INTO `groups`(`group_id`,`group_name`,`group_desc`) VALUES
(1,'USER','Regular users'),
(2,'ADMIN','Administration users');

INSERT  INTO `users`(`user_id`,`username`,`first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name`,`password`)VALUES(1,'john','John',NULL,'Doe','6e0b7076126a29d5dfcbd54835387b7b'),  /*john123*/ (2,'admin',NULL,NULL,NULL,'21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3');          /*admin*/
INSERT  INTO `user_groups`(`user_id`,`group_id`) VALUES (1,1),(2,1),    (2,2);
```

Comment: It's actually MySQL and not other SQL dialect, isn't it?

Comment: Event though I can perfectly execute your SQL statement from Netbeans in a fresh database, try to replace the backticks (`) with an apostrophe (').

Comment: Thanks @Joachim Let me try so